# How to use Target Definition in Product Configuration?

Tags: eclipse, definition, target, product, pde

I have a question related to Eclipse PDE development.

I'm using target definitions to manage my target platform, and would like to include all plugins from one particular target definition in one particular product configuration.

It seems like I'm missing an easier way than what I'm currently doing (manually selecting all the stuff from the target definition, and manually updating it whenever I add stuff to or remove stuff from the the target definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no direct way. I would encourage you to open an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDE). The indirect way of achieving this would be to use Launch Configurations. Create a plug-in based launch configuration and select whichever plug-ins you want from the Target. Now, create a new product configuration and chose the third option in the 'Initialize the file content' on the New Product Configuration wizard.